# Windows Phone Developer Registration (IpOverUsbSvc error) & mass storage mode (Lumia 735)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, lumia

as for other before me, I'm getting the IpOverUsbSvc error when trying to register my Lumia 735 (os windows phone 8.1, Denim) on my notebook (os windows 8.1, updated).
I've tried to restart the service, restart the phone, restart the notebook (because "why not?"), to reinstall the Windows Phone Development tools, to change the usb port, to delete from the known devices the phone and to change the cable (with the phone there wasn't a usb-cable, so i used my old one and I also tried to use another one), but nothing seems to work. Any other idea?

Also, somehow looking for an answer for my previous question, I came up with this [guide(1)](http://dev.windowsphone.com/it-it/OEM/docs/Phone_Testing/Configuring_IP_over_USB), where it says to connect the phone on mass storage mode to configure some debug settings. Not knowing how to connect it as a mass storage, I found this other [guide(2)](https://dev.windowsphone.com/it-it/OEM/docs/Debugging/Mass_storage_mode_and_boot_configuration_data), where the only thing it says is to press the camera button or the camera button and the volume down one. On lumia 735 there isn't a camera button, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. If you have registered more than one phones to your Microsoft/windows development account. than remove your present phone from account and rename it to the another registered phone name.(this worked for me)
             OR
2. if you don't have two registered phones remove your phone from developer account, rename your phone and connect(I wish it will work)